# How can I get OSM data in QGIS in a way that shows the nodes of roads intersecting as it would in JOSM?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-2

By using OSM data in QGIS, how can I show the nodes that are at the intersection of two roads? This is useful, because how will I know by just looking at the downloaded data from OSM into QGIS that the crossing of the two roads is an intersection or a bridge? In OSM a node shows that there is an intersection and that a car can turn from the one road onto the other, if the node is not there a car cannot turn, this is the case with a bridge.

I have tried downloading all the nodes with the key 'highway' but that doesn't include these nodes. That only downloads things like traffic lights.

Comment: You will have to download the ways from OSM. The intersection nodes don't have a special tag. I am not yet sure how to fulfill your task in an easy way.

Comment: [highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) is a tag mainly for *ways*, not for *nodes* (apart from a few exceptions). And as AndreJ already explained there is no special tag for an intersection node. This is because this information is already implicitly contained in the node information itself. A node is an intersection node if it is part of multiple ways. That's it.

Comment: AndreJ: You mentioned, "This can be determined by the layer tag". Could I still get these nodes to show by using that tag? That tag just refers to the level above or below ground. If a user accidently mapped the intersection incorrectly, the roads could cross each other on the same layer while not having a node at the crossing indicating an intersection where a vehicle can turn from the one road onto the other.

Comment: scai: That's exactly what I want to show in QGIS: " A node is an intersection node if it is part of multiple ways". But how do I show, or see these nodes?

Comment: Did you use a plugin that makes QGIS understand OSM data or did you convert the OSM data into a format that QGIS understands? If the latter, the information what nodes were shared by what ways might not be present in the imported data anymore.